# Why is FLT_MIN_EXP not equal to emin?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

The IEEE 754 standard defines the minimum and maximum values that can be represented in the exponent field, using the biased representation. For binary32, emax is defined as 127 and emin is defined to be 1-emax for all binary representations, that is, -126.

The C standard (I'm using the C99 revision here), however, defines `FLT_MIN_EXP` as:

> minimum negative integer such that `FLT_RADIX` raised to one less than that power is a normalized floating-point number, *e_min*.

The important words here are "one less than". So if `float` is a binary32, this means that `FLT_MIN_EXP` is -125.

Why is it defined this way? Or, to put it another way, why is `FLT_MIN_EXP` *not* the minimum exponent of a normal number?

Comment: I suspect this is related to how `frexp` returns a number with absolute value in [0.5, 1) instead of [1, 2), but I don't know the history.

Comment: That's a good guess.

Comment: Note that the same applies to the maximum exponent: the IEEE 754 standard chooses a description in which the maximum exponent is 127, but if a float is described in the form `2**e * f` description with `0.5 <= abs(f) < 1`, the maximum exponent is `128`. (There isn't such a thing as _the_ maximum exponent: the maximum exponent is dependent on the system that you're using to describe your floats.)

Comment: You still get valid floating point values at FLT_MIN_EXP, they are just not normalized anymore,  The distinction is important, once you reach the minimum exponent then you start losing accuracy in a hurry.  You can typically configure the processor to not try to represent denormal values (flush to zero), but that is not IEEE-754's favorite way.